# Why a using Integer.to_string faster then integer in string via {} about 6 times?

Tags: performance, optimization, elixir

I was doing polindrom_products exersice from Exercism and found intresting thing.

First version:

```
@doc """
Generates all palindrome products from an optionally given min factor (or 1) to a given max factor.
"""
@spec generate(non_neg_integer, non_neg_integer) :: map() 
def generate(max_factor, min_factor \\ 1) do
  palindromes = for a <- min_factor..max_factor,
                    b <- a..max_factor,
                    prod = a*b,
                    palindrome?(prod),
                    do: {prod, [a, b]}

  Enum.reduce(palindromes, %{}, fn {prod, pair}, acc ->
    Map.update(acc, prod, [pair], &(&1 ++ [pair]))
  end)
end

def palindrome?(n) do
  s = Integer.to_string(n)
  s == String.reverse(s)
end
```

Second version:

```
@doc """
Generates all palindrome products from an optionally given min factor (or 1) to a given max factor.
"""
@spec generate(non_neg_integer, non_neg_integer) :: map() 
def generate(max_factor, min_factor \\ 1) do
  palindromes = for a <- min_factor..max_factor,
                    b <- a..max_factor,
                    prod = a*b,
                    "#{prod}" == String.reverse("#{prod}"),
                    do: {prod, [a, b]}

  Enum.reduce(palindromes, %{}, fn {prod, pair}, acc ->
    Map.update(acc, prod, [pair], &(&1 ++ [pair]))
  end)
end
```

The first version faster than second about 6 times. Replace `"#{prod}" == String.reverse("#{prod}")` on `Integer.to_string(prod) == String.reverse(Integer.to_string(prod))` give a gain.

For example, use this test:

```
test "smallest palindromes from triple digit factors" do
  palindromes = Palindromes.generate(999, 100)
  assert palindromes |> Dict.keys |> Enum.sort |> hd == 10201
  assert palindromes[10201] == [[101, 101]]
end
```

First version executed in 0.7s, second version executed in 4s. I am using Elixir v1.1.1 and running code from Sublime Text on local machine.

What is the reason for that?

Comment: What version of Elixir are you on, and are you running in prod environment. It may be dev protocol dispatch that's slowing things down

Comment: I am using Elixir 1.1.1 and running code from Sublime Text on local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I am always wary of timing result reported for Elixir programs. Unless you are benchmarking from within the code, you're including the startup time for the BEAM VM and for such small codes that can skew the results significantly.

However, the crux comes down to why is

```
"#{prod}" == String.reverse("#{prod}")
```

much slower than

```
s = Integer.to_string(n)
s == String.reverse(s)
```

Lets pull the first line apart

```
"#{prod}"
```

-> This is actually 2 functions, the inner function uses the to_string protocol to convert prod to a string and then do string interpolation. Since it uses a protocol, rather than the direct Integer.to_string
function it will likely be slower until you consolidate protocols.

You do this twice in the same line, so you're already up to 4 function calls. Add the String.reverse and == and that is 6 function calls.

The second version properly caches the result and only does 3 function
calls.

If you want to investigate these kinds of micro benchmarks further I highly recommend the benchfella library. 
https://github.com/alco/benchfella

Comment: Thank for explanation and benchfella!